404 not found error on requesting a html file defined by my springboot controller
I came across a problem developing a java springboot application.
So I have this Controller and it should map /game to a file index.html that should be loaded
@Controller
public class ViewRenderer {

    @GetMapping("/game")
    public String getIndex() {
        return "index";
    }

}

The file index.html is located under src->main->resources->index.html
I also added the thymeleaf dependency in the pom file
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

However, when calling localhost:{port}/game, the well known 404 error is provided. I do not have a clue on why the file is not found at this point. My IDE is Intellij, and I use Java 17 for my implementation. Any suggestions?
I tried several things, including different versions of thymeleaf in the pom file and restarting the ide, but with zero success.

Just move the file index.html to this location: src/main/resources/templates
